# How to find a js object in a string?

Tags: php, json, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to write a regex to find a js object in the string.

```
$test = "var contactData = {
    'address': '',
    'email': '',
    'phone': '09121269001',
    'fax': ''
};";

preg_match_all('/^contactData\s[=:]\s{(.*)};$/m', $test, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);
```

and here is the results I got.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  1 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Comment: What are you trying to get? and why not json_decode()?

Comment: When asking for a regex-based solution, it is best to provide 2 or 3 different sample strings so that the best possible solution can be provided.  If all of the strings are strictly/reliably in this format, then regex is not the best approach.  Please include in your question, the exact output that you desire given your input sample(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If regex is what you want then I think this is a good solution.

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/kOh

```
preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/", $test, $Matches);
```

And as you can see from the image `$match[0]` and `[1]` is address, `[2]` and `[3]` email and so on.

[image]

---

If you want each group as a new variable you can use the following code to create variables instead of using the array.

```
$test = "var contactData = {
    'address': 'foobar',
    'email': 'fofo@foo.com',
    'phone': '09121269001',
    'fax': '1234'
};";


preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/", $test, $Matches);

foreach($Matches[1] as $val){
    $$val = next($Matches[1]);
}

echo $address . "\n" . $email ."\n" . $phone ."\n". $fax;
```

Output:

```
foobar
fofo@foo.com
09121269001
1234
```

https://3v4l.org/CMvYB

Answer (score 1):

This would be the regex:

```
/\'(.*)\'\: \'(.*)\'/
```

Proof of concept posted here:
https://xrg.es/#12zb4f1

```
preg_match_all("/\'(.*)\'\: \'(.*)\'/", "$test", $matches, null, 0);
```

[image: Regex result]

So `$matches[1][2]` is = to `phone`
So `$matches[2][2]` is = to `09121269001`

Comment: This answer has unnecessary escaping on the single quotes and colon in the pattern -- which should not be taught.  There is no need to double quote `$test`.  There is no need to declare the 4th and 5th parameters in `preg_match_all()`.  You could also consider using a negated character class `[^']` instead of a dot as it will be more efficient.  Whenever submitting a regex-based solution on SO, please do your very best to provide the most-accurate, most-efficient, and most-brief pattern.  This way future SO readers will learn best practices.

Comment: The site, that you demo'ed your pattern on, is not great because it displays a verbose php expression -- as I have mentioned in my previous comment.  Also, it doesn't tell you the "steps" that were required in the pattern.  I recommend testing and demoing on https://regex101.com/ because it tells you how efficient your pattern is.  Knowing the steps helps you to refine your pattern to improve efficiency.  You can also compare the other answers' step count to see how yours compares.  This will be very helpful as a self-education tool..

Answer (score 1):

The `m` modifier makes the anchors (`^` and `$`) match 1 line at a time. Your first line also starts with `var` so you can't use a leading anchor or you need to add that. You can use the `s` modifier with either of the for mentioned approaches and this would work.

```
/contactData\s[=:]\s\{(.*)\};$/s
```

or

```
/^var contactData\s[=:]\s\{(.*)\};$/s
```

Demos: https://regex101.com/r/xCE6UD/2/, https://regex101.com/r/xCE6UD/1/

You also should escape the `{}`s. With `.*` as greedy you will match until the last `}` in your string, which would be incorrect if you had multiple JSON strings. An alternative approach could also be:

```
contactData\s[=:]\s\{([^}]+)};$
```

https://regex101.com/r/xCE6UD/3/

Answer (score 0):

**It is contraindicated to use regex to parse a json object** when `json_decode()` was specifically designed to do this very task.  It only requires that you prepare the string before decoding it.  `json_decode()` does all the necessary work to prepare a readily accessible associative array.

The following snippet will first give you the end result, then *Tarantino* it to give you all of the steps that lead up to it.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e5a7528d4fcd44296baa05970a43ba752275f72))

```
$test = "var contactData = {
    'address': '',
    'email': '',
    'phone': '09121269001',
    'fax': ''
};";
// step #4 / final output -> use json_decode to generate associative array:
var_export(json_decode(rtrim(strstr(str_replace("'",'"',$test),'{'),';'),true));

echo "\n\n";
// step #1 -> swap single quotes for double quotes:
var_export(str_replace("'",'"',$test));
echo "\n";
// step #2 -> extract json object start to end of string:
var_export(strstr(str_replace("'",'"',$test),'{'));
echo "\n";
// step #3 -> trim trailing semi-colon from substring (several funcs can do this part)
var_export(rtrim(strstr(str_replace("'",'"',$test),'{'),';'));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'address' => '',
  'email' => '',
  'phone' => '09121269001',
  'fax' => '',
)

'var contactData = {
    "address": "",
    "email": "",
    "phone": "09121269001",
    "fax": ""
};'
'{
    "address": "",
    "email": "",
    "phone": "09121269001",
    "fax": ""
};'
'{
    "address": "",
    "email": "",
    "phone": "09121269001",
    "fax": ""
}'
```